# loop array of locations in separate thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, multithreading

I'm working on an application for the iPhone and I'm keeping track of the users current location. When the `didupdateLocations` delegate method actually executes i would like to test  if the location in the NSArray is in a predefined array the contains other locations, this array mind you could grow over time.

I'm running a for loop within this method to test against my own array of locations but i would like to move that to a separate thread. So in case my own array with multiple locations grows to a large number the for loop does not freeze my UI. 
I have tried it like this but I'm getting undesirable results. I understand that the location tracking definitely happens in a separate thread. However those `didupdateLocations`  execute on a separate thread. The Apple doc's are not very clear on the matter. My end goal again is to compare against my array and not lock the UI.

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)thisLocation {

    dispatch_queue_t queue= dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    // get the last object in the array of locations
    CLLocation* location = [thisLocation lastObject];

     dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         [self checkmyArray:location];
     });

}



 -(void)checkmyArray:(CLLocation *)workingLocation{

    NSLog(@"SoundTheAlarm");
     int alarm_on_c = 0;
     NSUInteger tmp_count = [theData.LocationsObjectArray count];
     BOOL alarm;
     NSMutableDictionary * tempObject;
     CLLocationDistance distance = 0.0;


    for (int i = 0; i < tmp_count; i++) {

        tempObject= [theData.LocationsObjectArray objectAtIndex:i];

         thisLoc = [[tempObject objectForKey:@"onoff"] isEqual:@YES];


        if (thisLoc) {


            //check if we are near that location
            double lat = [[tempObject objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
            double lon = [[tempObject objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

            // goal = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:40.097771 longitude:-74.941399];
            goal = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];

            // check the destination between current location and goal location - in meters
            distance = [goal distanceFromLocation:workingLocation];

            NSLog(@"distance %f\n", distance);
        }


        // if distance from goal is less than 350 meters
        if (distance <= 350){

                [self scheduleNotification:[tempObject objectForKey:@"name"]];

                // turn off tracking for this location
                [tempObject setObject:@NO forKey:@"onoff"];
                [theData.LocationsObjectArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tempObject];

                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                ExtendedSavedCellTableViewCell *cell = (ExtendedSavedCellTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
                cell.switchView.on = NO;

                // save the update to the switch to the database as well
                NSString *lat = [tempObject objectForKey:@"latitude"];

                /*check to determine if the uiswitch is turned off or on.*/

                [self fetchedResultsController:@NO lat:lat index:path];
                [self displayAlertViewForAlarm:[tempObject objectForKey:@"name"]];


}

-(void)displayAlertViewForAlarm:(NSString *)nameOfLocation{

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {


    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Destination reached"
                                                      message:nameOfLocation
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Go Away"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Notify", nil];


    [myAlert show];
     });



}
```

Comment: What undesirable results are you getting? What are you trying to get?

Comment: The alert executes multiple times. I just want the alert to display when the goal is within 350 meters

Comment: The code will execute each time the location updates. That may be more often than you wish to execute that code.

Comment: It sounds like you may want region monitoring:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW61

Comment: @Fabian Thats true so would you suggest just executing after a certain amount perhaps every 10th `didupdateLocations`.

Comment: Maybe you should set a distance filter on the location manager: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to use threads in iOS if you can at all avoid it.  In your case, I'd implement the function which does the looping to automatically pop out of the loop after too many iterations and then schedule the next chunk of iterating to happen in another pass through the event loop.  In other words, something like this:

```
- (void) checkLocationsStartingAt:(NSNumber)start
{
    NSInteger s = (start) ? [start intValue] : 0;
    for (i = s; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i > TOO_MANY) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(checkLocationsStartingAt:)
                       withObject:@(i) 
                       afterDelay:0.001];
            return;
        } else {
            // check element at i
        }
    }
}
```

see: [NSObject Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)

Comment: *this*? I guess you mean *self*

Comment: Andrew I'm just one bit confused the TOO_MANY gets populated from where? sorry for the noob question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using threads in iOS.  It's encouraged and can be greatly beneficial in many cases, especially if you're using something like GCD (which @Miguel is).

Comment: @Miguel You'd define that as a constant elsewhere in your program (e.g., at the top of the *.m file)

Comment: @vikingosegundo Oops... doing lots of JavaScript lately... :-)

Comment: @MikeS I can see where you're coming from. Threads can be a powerful tool, but they can also be very tricky and create some very subtle bugs. In general, I prefer solving problems without threads where possible.

Comment: @AndrewMiner That's very true about threads possibly creating tricky and subtle bugs and, if you can solve a problem without using threads, great. My point was just that it isn't **bad** to use threads in iOS. In fact, quite a few APIs in iOS execute on separate threads (like CoreLocation) and you may not have a choice in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking one location against an array of other locations.
You display an alert for time you are closer than 350m from a location.
You could be within 350m of many items in the list. 
You have no code prevent multiple alerts.

So you will sometimes have many alerts.

You have a couple options. One will probably suit your needs better than the others. Possibly one I didn't list.

- You could re-use a single `UIAlertView` instance and check the
  `visible` property on it. If it's already visible, do nothing.
- You could break out of the loop once you get a single "hit" on being
  <350m.
- You could stick in a `BOOL` which records if you've shown the alert and
  check the `BOOL` every time before you show the alert again.